# What is the TranslationService in Android?

Tags: android

A `WebView` can manage `ViewTranslationRequest` objects. The [JavaDoc for `ViewTranslationRequest`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/translation/ViewTranslationRequest) says:

> Wrapper class representing a translation request associated with a `View` to be used by `TranslationService`.

`TranslationService` is hyperlinked (from the same document as above) to `android.service.translation.TranslationService`. But I can't find any information about this class online and its documentation page just gives a 404. What is this?

Comment: You may want to look at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/translation/TranslationManager which is the bridge to the translation service client side.

Comment: Also, this is new stuff added in API 31.  My guess is its not ready to be public yet.